# Unable to generate release apk in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am unable to generate signed apk. The app debugs and runs fine but signed apk is not generated. If I do minifyEnabled false the signed apk is generated.

```
 buildTypes {
        debug { debuggable false }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
    // compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    // RecyclerView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
    // event bus
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'

    }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The Warning:

> Warning:there were 128 instances of library classes depending on
>   program classes.You must avoid such dependencies, since the program
>   classes will be processed, while the library classes will remain
>   unchanged.
>   (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
>
> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please
>   correct the above warnings first.
>       :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. >
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

```
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpConnection
Warning:library class com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.RedirectException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends or implements program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.AllClientPNames extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.AllClientPNames extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.ClientParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestDefaultHeaders extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnConnectionParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.cookie.params.CookieSpecParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.ClientParamsStack extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper extends or implements program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.TunnelRefusedException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpException 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser extends or implements program class org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer extends or implements program class org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer extends or implements program class org.apache.http.io.SessionOutputBuffer 
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody 
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache 
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption 
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement 
Warning:org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Duration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Instant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.MutablePeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Period: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString 
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDuration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractPeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.RequestLine 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy 
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor 
Warning:there were 107 unresolved references to classes or interfaces. You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress the warnings with '-dontwarn' options. (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) 
Warning:there were 128 instances of library classes depending on program classes. You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged. (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency) 
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

I tried cleaning and building several times but the same error.

Comment: please add your warnings here (can find in message view)

Comment: Lack of research. There is a link there ([this one](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#dependency)) that helps you solve it

Comment: Please get into the habit of posting your logs using the code formatting device (this adds a scroll bar to make the question less lengthy to browse through). I have tried to add code formatting, but they formatted onto one line, so it seems they could do with copying+pasting again to restore the line breaks. I have added them in a quote block for now.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because your Proguard is enabled:

Try updating your proguard file with following lines:

```
// org.apache
-dontwarn org.apache.**
// Jackson
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
//OkHttp
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
// Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
//Okio
-dontwarn okio.**
//Joda Time Convert
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
```

This is just to help you fix your apk building process, but you have to test your signed apk to check if there is any reference that it should require and is not getting because of code obfuscation.

I suggest go through the proguard manual and also go through [troubleshooting](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedclass) to fix if any issues encounter